# Why is $x^2-2ux+1$, where $u = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})$, irreducible in $\mathbb Q(u)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

My textbook states that $x^2-2ux+1$, where $u = \cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ is clearly irreducible in $\mathbb Q(u)$.

Is this obvious?

I tried to write it as a product of linear factors, but I found this difficult because I do not know what an element in $\mathbb Q(u)$ looks like.

Any insights?

Comment: this is false for $n=6$

Comment: For $n=3$ it's reducible over $\Bbb Q$. It'd be pretty easy to explain why if it were $x^2-2\cos(\frac{2\pi}{n})x+1$ instead (the discriminant would be imaginary).

Comment: Yes, it is. I hadn't even thought about doubting the textbook. I'll check if I have overlooked something.

Comment: Perhaps it is actually $\;u=\cos\frac{2\pi}n\;$ and **not** $\;u=\color{red}2\cos\frac{2\pi}n\;$ ? That would automatically render that quadratic irreducible over the reals...

Comment: @DonAntonio That is exactly the case. Sorry for your trouble. The answer is clear now.

Comment: @Improve, edit your question's title, too.

Comment: @DonAntonio Can't I just delete the question? It is based on me reading the text incorrectly. I do not know what the general feeling about such things are.

Comment: Well @improve: first, many people already read the question and some even commented, not to mention that there'salready an answer. What's the point of deleting ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Well, no other reason than that the question was originally based on a false assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we in fact have $\;u=\cos\frac{2\pi}n\;$ , then the quadratic's discriminant is

$$\Delta:=b^2-4ac=\cos^2\frac{2\pi}n-4<0$$

and we're done...

Comment: Um, $b=-2u{}{}$.

Comment: Read the comments below the question, @seaturtles

Comment: I did, and even commented before you, but I'm telling you: while $u$ was corrected from $2\cos$ to just $\cos$, the polynomial is still $x^2-2ux+1$.

Comment: I see what you mean, @seaturtles...yet I think the intention is for $\;x^2-ux+1\;$ ...at least that's what I understood and meant before. Let's see if the OP addresses this, though it doesn't matter much I think, as $$\cos^2\frac{2\pi}n-1<0\;\;\forall\,1<n\in\Bbb N$$

Comment: Of course, you get $\Delta=-4\sin^2$, which is much more elegant than $\cos^2-4$. Also, the quadratic $x^2-2\cos()x+1$ appears in nature as $(x-\cos)^2+\sin^2$. Plus, OP already checked back with the problem and changed $u=2\cos$ to $u=\cos$ but did not change the polynomial. All these facts considered, I overwhelmingly believe $x^2-2ux+1$ was exactly as intended.